# On page refresh html tag IDs,classes and names are not getting preserved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am taking the data from textbox and option field using AJAX request to the server storing it to db, creating the row and attaching it to table.

```
$("#addRecord").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var question_id = $("#questionId").val();
var question_text = $("#questionText").val();
$.ajax({
    url: "addContestAnswer.html",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"questionId": question_id, "contestText": question_text},
    success: function(data){
       addRows(data.questionId,data.contestText); 
       // calling the function to create row
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        console.log("error" + status);
    }
  });   
});
```

creating the row

```
function addRows(questionId ,questionText) {

    var deleteButton = '<a href="#" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary">delete</a>';
    var fileUpload = '<input type="file" name="supportingDocument" accept="application/pdf" id="uploadSupportingDoc" />';
    var row = "<tr><td class=\"ques_id\">"+questionId+"</td><td class=\"ques_text\">"+questionText+"</td><td class=\"ques_file\">"+fileUpload+"</td><td></td><td>"+deleteButton+"</td></tr>";
    $('#recordTable tr:last').after(row);

    $("#questionId").val("-1");
    $("#questionText").val("");

}
```

So far the html generated is looking good. 
But when I'm refreshing the page, none of the html IDs,classes and Names of generated row are getting preserved.

**generated row after ajax call**

```
<tr>
  <td class="ques_id">17</td>
  <td class="ques_text">asddgfdg</td>
  <td class="ques_file"><input type="file" name="supportingDocument" accept="application/pdf" id="uploadSupportingDoc"></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><a href="#" id="deleteButton" class="btn btn-primary">delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

**After refreshing the page**

```
<tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>asddgfdg</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="" id=""></td>
    <td></td>                                   
    <td><a href="#" id="" class="btn btn-primary">delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

why is it happening? am I missing some tweak while generating the row, if not what's the solution?

Comment: Is data inserted in database? Have you checked that? Your url seems to call `addContestAnswer.html`. Is this a correct one?

Comment: Yes data is inserted. I am facing the issue in generated html id.

Comment: Will you add the code of generating html after refresh?

Comment: okay check the I've added it please check last two snippets.

Comment: I think you forgot to query the data from your database.And i think you did not able to save questions info because your url is `url: "addContestAnswer.html"`. if you have process the saving of the data in that file it should not be .html

Comment: Dynamically added elements will never be preserved after page refresh.

Comment: @jameshwartlopez  I mean why are these classes and ids class="ques_id", class="ques_text", class="ques_file", id="deleteButton" are getting removed. please check the last two snippets.

Comment: @Azim so what is the solution sir?

Comment: @piechuckerr you are adding the row using jquery by calling your function `addRows` when the page refresh, the elements you have added will be removed meaning it doesn't stay at the page.. so to add it you must query the data using php then create the row again using php .. so that it will stay in your page.

Comment: You can perform an `ajax` call on page load and add your elements to the container. @piechuckerr

Comment: @jameshwartlopez okay got it mate, Thank you!